# Swift inferring a completion handler closure to be the default @nonescaping instead of @escaping when completion handler explicitly uses @escaping

Tags: swift, closures, swift4, completionhandler

Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1

In the order processing app I'm working on, the user may do a search for orders already processed or submitted. When that happens, it will check to see if it has a cache of orders, and if it does not, it will refill that cache using an asynchronous API request, then check the cache again.

The function that refills the cache is a private static one that accepts an escaping completion handler. Whenever I have used that completion handler in the past, all I had to do was add a closure at the end of the function call. This was before I was instructed to make a cache of all data wherever possible, and only use the API to refill that cache. Since then, the function has become private, because there will never be a need to call the API directly from anywhere but within this class.

Now, when I put the closure directly after the function call, it's giving me an error that basically says I'm passing a @nonescaping closure instead of an @escaping closure:

```
"Cannot invoke 'getAndCacheAPIData' with an argument list of type '(type: Codable.Type, (String?) -> Void)', Expected an argument list of type '(type: CodableClass.Type, @escaping (String?) -> Void)'"
```

I've never had to explicitly declare a closure to be @escaping before, nether does it seem to be possible. I suspect that because the function is both private AND static, there's some kind of issue happening with the way closures are inferred to be @escaping. I'm out of my depth. I could try converting the static class to a singleton, but I'm hesitant to refactor a bunch of working code because of one error until I'm absolutely sure that change will resolve the issue, and that what I'm trying to do isn't possible unless I change my approach.

Here's the code:

```
public static func fillSearchResultArray<ManagedClass: NSManagedObject>(query:String, parameters:[String], with type: ManagedClass.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (String?)->Void)
{
    let codableType:Codable.Type
    switch type
    {
        case is ClientTable.Type:
            codableType = ClientData.self
        case is OrderTable.Type:
            codableType = OrderData.self
        case is ProductTable.Type:
            codableType = ProductData.self
        default:
            completionHandler("Unrecognized type.")
            return
    }
    let fetchedData:[ManagedClass]
    do
    {
        fetchedData = try PersistenceManager.shared.fetch(ManagedClass.self)
    }
    catch
    {
        completionHandler(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    if fetchedData.isEmpty
    {
        AppNetwork.getAndCacheAPIData(type: codableType)//error here
        {(firstErrorString) in
            //move search array data to the cache
            if firstErrorString.exists
            {
                completionHandler(error)
            }
            else
            {
                AppNetwork.fillSearchResultArray(query: query, parameters: parameters, type: type)
                { errorString in
                    completionHandler(errorString)
                }
            }
        }

        return
    }
    else
    { ...
```

The signature of the function being called:

```
private static func getAndCacheAPIData <CodableClass: Any & Codable>(type:CodableClass.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (String?)->Void)
```

Why is swift inferring this closure to be the default @nonescaping when before it always inferred it to be @escaping?

Comment: I'm much more suspicious of `CodableClass.Type` in the signature (rather than `Codable.Type`, which is expected). What is that? What is the signature of `getAndCacheAPIData`? And what's the definition of `codableType`?

Comment: private static func getAndCacheAPIData <CodableClass: Any & Codable>(type:CodableClass.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (String?)->Void)

Comment: CodableClass is just a dynamic type so I can decode the API data into more than one Codable struct without having a different function for each. And it works with no issues for any Codable data type I put in there.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Swift so I might be doing that in a less than optimal way

Comment: `codableType` is assigned earlier in the code based on an enum value, it will always evaluate to some type conforming to Codable

Comment: ...oh, I see what you're saying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the closure, or static, or private. It has to do with the type parameter. You cannot call this method:

```
private static func getAndCacheAPIData <CodableClass: Any & Codable>(type:CodableClass.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (String?)->Void)
```

with a variable of type `Codable.Type`. The type value you pass must be a concrete type, known at compile-time. If you want to pass a variable, you can't use a generic. It would have to be:

```
private static func getAndCacheAPIData(type: Codable.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (String?)->Void)
```

Alternately, you can call this as:

```
 AppNetwork.getAndCacheAPIData(type: Int.self) {(firstErrorString) in ... }
```

or some other known-at-compile-time type.

Probably what you really want here is something like:

```
let completion: (String?) -> Void = {(firstErrorString) in ... }

switch ... {
    case ...:
        AppNetwork.getAndCacheAPIData(type: Int.self, completion: completion)
    case ...:
        AppNetwork.getAndCacheAPIData(type: String.self, completion: completion)
    ...
```

The basic problem is that protocols do not conform to themselves, so a variable of type `Codable.Type` does not satisfy the `: Codable` requirement. This comes down to the same reason you can't just call:

```
AppNetwork.getAndCacheAPIData(type: Codable.self) {...}
```

Alternately, you could refactor it this way:

```
private static func handleAPI<CodableClass: Codable>(type: CodableClass.Type) {
    getAndCacheAPIData(type: type.self) { _ in ... the completion handler ..}
}


switch ... {
    case ...:
        AppNetwork.handleAPI(type: Int.self)
    case ...:
        AppNetwork.handleAPI(type: String.self)
    ...
```

Side note: `Any &` is meaningless here. You just meant `<CodableClass: Codable>`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue. I was reading CodableClass and Codable as the same thing, I never noticed they were different. Doh.